# How do I give a 'calendar event' an ID so that I can manipulate it in jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, fullcalendar

I'm using the FullCalendar plugin. And I have events on the calendar. I also have this list on the right side that lists out the events.

How do I give the fullcalendar event an ID? (like a css #id).

I want to click on the event and have the right list scroll to the specific list item based on the event.

link to the plugin - http://fullcalendar.io/
link to my code - http://codepen.io/anon/pen/RWYEvK

```
$('#calendar').fullCalendar({
    // put your options and callbacks here

    height: 345,

    events: [
        {
            start : '2015-11-12', // Year, Month, Day
            color : '#00adef', // Label color
            textColor : '#FFF', // Text color
            category : '1',
            //url : '#',
            id : 123
        },
        {
            title : '3:00pm Another Event', // Event Title
            start : '2015-11-17', // Year, Month, Day
            color : '#fc6264', // Label color
            textColor : '#FFF', // Text color
            category : '2'
        },
        {
            title : '3:00pm Another Event', // Event Title
            start : '2015-11-25', // Year, Month, Day
            color : '#00a652', // Label color
            textColor : '#FFF', // Text color
            category : '3'
        }
    ],
    eventRender: function eventRender( event, element, view ) {
        return ['all', event.category].indexOf($('#category-select').val()) >= 0
    },  

    // Scroll-To function
    eventClick: function(){
        $(this).click(function() {
            $('#event-list').animate({scrollTop: $("#li-1").offset().top}, 1000);
            $('#li-1').addClass('hov');
        });
    }
});


// Class filtering
$('#category-select').on('change',function(){
    $('#calendar').fullCalendar('rerenderEvents');
})
```

Answer (score 0):

You are very close! You don't need to bind any element yourself with `$(this).click...`. the `eventClick` callback you have takes 3 arguments `eventClick: function(calEvent, jsEvent, view) {`. What you want to use is the calEvent argument. So, if your right list elements have a specified id like `#li-number` and your jsEvent has an id property, you can determine which list element to select based on the id property of the jsEvent:

```
...
// Scroll-To function
eventClick: function(calEvent, jsEvent, view){
   var listElementId = "#li-" + calEvent.id;
   $('#event-list').animate({scrollTop: $(listElementId).offset().top}, 1000);
   $(listElementId).addClass('hov');
}
...
```

I hope that helps!